# Unchecked operation warning

Tags: java, vector, unchecked

What is causing this warning in my program>? I'm giving the inputs by command line. I'm getting this warning for all vector programs.

```
import java.util.*;
class vect
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Vector v=new Vector();
        int length=args.length;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            v.addElement(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Objects in vector are :");
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(v.elementAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
C:\myJava>javac vect.java
Note: vect.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`
```

Comment: `Vector` should be type safe.

Comment: If you had followed the compiler’s suggestion and executed `javac -Xlint:unchecked vect.java`, you could have answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `Vector` without a type. You are then adding to it the arguments which are Strings. This Vector should be type safe.

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
```